# Hw to return mongoose to Glabal Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How to return data from query from `mongoose` ?

```
// index.js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var { MONGODB } = require("./config.js");
var result;

const type = require('./models/Type')
mongoose
.connect(MONGODB, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => {
  type.find({}, (er , db) => { return db })
    .then((res) => {
      result = res
      return res
    })
})
.then((res)=> {
  console.log(res) // undifine
  console.log(result) // undifine
})
```

Comment: You don't return anything from the first then()

Comment: how about global varialbel ?